# How can I retrieve brands based on specific category?

Tags: python, html, django

How can I retrieve/filter the brands related to a specific category in a view or a template? I can retrieve products based on category, but, I want to be able to retrieve the brands related to that category? Do I need to create a model for brands separately?

Here are my product and category models

Category Model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = ('category')
        verbose_name_plural = ('categories')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])
```

Product Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='brands')
    retailer        = models.ForeignKey(Retailer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='suppliers')
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    url             = models.URLField()
    description     = models.TextField()
    color           = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    material        = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    weight          = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    dimensions      = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    available       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    price           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    cost_price      = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image_1         = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/')
    image_2         = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/')
    image_3         = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/')
    created         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('?',)
        verbose_name = ('product')
        verbose_name_plural = ('products')
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

Here is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Product, Category, Brand

# Create your views here.
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products   = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
       category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
       products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,'product_list.html',
    {'category': category,
    'categories': categories,
    'products': products})

def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,
        id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    return render(request, 'product_detail.html',
        {'product': product})
```

Here is the template

```html
            <div class="container mt-2">
                <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                        <ul id="menu" class="list-unstyled">
                            <span>
                                <li
                        {% if not category %}class="active"{% endif %}>
                                    <a href="{% url 'shop:products' %}">All</a>
                                </li>
                            </span>
                        {% for c in categories %}

                            <span>
                                <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %} class="active"{% endif %}>
                                    <a href="{{c.get_absolute_url }}" class="text-uppercase">{{c.name}}</a>
                                </li>
                            </span>
                        {% endfor %}

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-container mt-2">
                <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                  {% for product in products %}

                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <a href="{{product.get_absolute_url}}">
                                <img src="{{product.image_1.url}}" class="img-fluid" />
                                <img src="{{product.image_2.url}}" class="img-fluid img-top" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="card-body py-1">
                                <a href="{{product.get_absolute_url}}" class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase" style=" letter-spacing: 0.1em;">{{product.title}}</a>
                                <p class="font-weight-light py-2 text-center" style="font-size: 1em; letter-spacing: 0.2em; color:#021C24;">£ {{product.price}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                  {% endfor %}

                </div>
            </div>
```

Here are the URLs.
                from django.urls import path
                from . import views
                app_name = 'shop'
                urlpatterns = [
                    path('products/', views.product_list, name='products'),
                    path('
                /', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
                    path('
                    /
                        /', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
                ]

Comment: I think the indentation in your post is broken/off.

Comment: Hi, which part? I have reveiwed it and it looks fine. Thanks

Comment: It looks quite fine to me. You are getting `Product`s based on a `slug` of a `Category`. So you (for example) hit `/products/my-category`, you get `Product`s for only `Category` with slug `my-category`. Can you also provide related URLs? You probably will have to create two separate URLs for it, I'm not sure if you have done so or not.

Comment: Hello Erdin, i added the related URLs as asked.